# Defining Java Variables

Tags: java

Could I ask what these three lines do?

```
public static Level level;
level = new Level();
level.render(g); //do the above have anything to do with this?
```

also what does this do

```
block[x][y].render(g);
```

and what does this do:

```
block[x][y].id = whatever
```

sorry about these questions being really noobish but I am a newbie to Java

Comment: What do you *think* those lines do? What happened when you traced through the code with a debugger or a piece of paper and a pencil?

Comment: The first should be answered by [this article](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/declaringvars.htm). The rest by [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Learn to use Google, it will be of massive help to you.

Comment: part of those questions can only be answered in a given context. How can we know what a render() method does if you don't provide the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Level level;
level = new Level();
```

is same as

```
public static Level level = new Level();
```

If you just consider the statement

```
public static Level level;
```

level being an static variable is set to null.(All instance variables and static variables are assigned default values unlike local variables.)

```
level.render(g);
```

This is calling an function render() defined in the class Level. It calls it in the instance of Level stored earlier in the variable level and passes in the parameter g.

```
block[x][y].render(g);
```

means you have an 2D array which stores objects of class which has the definition of function render() in it.

```
block[x][y].id = whatever
```

means you take the Object stored in the 2D array and assign value to the variable id defined in that Object. Again if you are doing this outside class in which id is define then id variables must be in scope(public/protected in that sense).

Comment: but what about `block[x][y].id = whatever`?

Comment: Not an instance variable, it's `static`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah it's a class variable not an instance variable. None the less both are assigned default values. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AniketThakur so does that create a variable of the type Level. What is the type Level? Just a random type that stores what type of data? And is Level() an array

Comment: @iijjaa Level is a instance of Custom user defined class. It will store what you want it to store... Level is a class. I would suggest refer to some getting started with java tutorials.

Comment: @AniketThakur could you recommend a good Java getting started tutorial I know Javascript very well but all the beginner Java tutorials assume you have had no programming knowledge so could you reccomend a java beginner tutorial that assumes that you have already had some programming knowledge

Comment: Google **head first java** ,download the pdf and get started.